How to render node-name next to node-point in a way that it has collision-avoidance in PyVis
Issue
In many PyVis examples text is being ignored and just overlayed, e.g. node-names.
Wanted
I want to prevent that text is being overlayed.
Screenshot: How it should look like

In abstract terms:
The developer is trying to assign every single letter of an entry a fixed space that has collision-avoidance and is dragable.
Question
How to make node-names as buttons/labels with variable character-length that contain text so that they have collision avoidance?
Disclaimer: I am also willing to compensate someone for helping us.

Can you give the [example] code for the image. If this shows the visualization not wanted, how would the wanted visualization look like?
